# Why is there a wave spring washer and a plain washer between these two sealed bearings?

Tags: appliances, washer

I replaced the bearings in my Vitamix blender and I’m curious as to why there is a wave washer and a plain washer with a smaller diameter in between the two sealed ball bearings.

My guess is that the wave washer will prevent chattering between the two bearings and the plain washer provides support to the inner area of each bearing.

[image]

[image: Assembled on the drive shaft]

---

Edit: Here's a photo of the completed blade assembly. The two bearings on the shaft are inside the threaded cup. The inside of the cup is threaded as well and the bearings are held in place with threadlocker.

[image: Blade assembly]

Comment: Do you have any assembly drawings for this? The outer washer makes sense to me, but the inner one would only make sense in certain contexts. The fact that there are two bearings with little spacing between them is odd to me, so a drawing would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry I don't have assembly drawings but I've added a photo of the fully-assembled blade assembly. In what contexts would it make sense to have the inner washer?

Comment: Ah, so this does appear as I expected, with bearings on either side of a seal. I'll write up a full answer.

Comment: This is a less expensive way to create a thrust bearing to keep the gears from moving under a varying load. I see double bearings on small gearboxes but usually larger gearboxes use true thrust bearings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a blender is a small appliance. See our [on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ball bearings typically have some axial play or backlash

Take a look at the cross section for a ball bearing.

[image: ball bearing cross section]

The inner and outer race are rarely manufactured to fully constrain the ball. If you take a bearing and hold the inner race, you'll notice you can move the outer race back and forth slightly. This motion would typically cause extra wear, friction, and vibration.

### "[Preloading](http://www.nmbtc.com/bearings/engineering/preload)" resolves these issues.

In the image above, the outer race would be pushed to the left while the inner race would be pushed to the right. This causes the ball to only contact each race at one point on the ball's surface. Connecting these two points creates an imaginary line, which is shown at some angle, known as the contact angle, relative to a radial line.

### Both of the inner and outer races move together to reduce wear

Typically, you don't want slip between the bearing ID or OD and the mating surface, so the inner races of both bearings move together and the outer races of both bearings move together.

### Two bearings help improve shaft alignment

A single bearing, because of the play mentioned earlier, can allow the shaft angle to vary. This is called shaft misalignment. Typically, bearings are spaced further apart, but using two bearings helps constrain the shaft misalignment greatly because the angular tolerance between two subsequent bearings is lower than that of a single bearing.

### Putting this all together

The inner washer is used to space the bearing races apart so they don't rub (and wear the seals) while also coupling the motion of the inner races. This appears to be clamped rigidly with an acorn nut above the blades. This, however, doesn't constrain the outer races, which is why a wavy washer is used. Clamping the inner races together compresses the wavy washer, which forces the outer races apart, fully constraining the balls with opposing contact angles.

Comment: Great explanation! To clarify, the "mating surface" for the ID of the bearing would be the shaft and for the OD it would be the cup? Just so that everything's clear: if the two bearings are on top of each other as in this assembly, then the wave washer forces the outer race of the lower bearing down and the outer race of the upper bearing up, right? This is what causes "opposing contact angles" in each bearing in order to lower the angular tolerance of the shaft?

Comment: You are correct about the mating surfaces and the direction of the forces created by the wavy washer. Because of the proximity of the two bearings, the angular tolerance isn't much better than that of a single bearing, but it does help slightly.